# Javascript How to read csv properly?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am trying to read contents of cvs file which is created by `save as` on Microsoft Excel and contains Korean.

When I try to read text in the file, because of encoding problem, it would give something like `#,��¥,���� ȸ���,���� ȸ���,��/���θ�,�⹮��,����ȣ(�⹮��),���,������,��������,��û����,��û�������,������ȭ��ȣ,������ȣ`

I've tried to add encoding option on `readAsText`, but without luck.(I've tried ANSI and UTF-8)

How could I read the content properly?

Javascript:

```
var reader = new FileReader;

reader.readAsText(csvFile);

reader.onload = (e) => {
    console.log(reader.result);
}
```

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated .Thank you in advance.

Comment: First thing to check is file encoding. Should be utf8, but you have to set it in excel before saving as csv (don't know if it's possible in excel). If file is properly encoded with utf8, javascript should be able to read it

Comment: I added `euc-kr` on encoding option and it works well.